# .htaccess - redirect individual urls to url with query string

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm looking to do the opposite of a common query with .htaccess files.

I want to redirect a standard url to a url with a query string, similar to below:

> test.com/directory/pagename
>
> to:
>
> test.com/template?id=1

I don't require pattern matching of any form, I just want to write out a separate redirect for each one. For example:

> test.com/colours/red = test.com/template?id=5
>
> test.com/colours/yellow = test.com/template?id=3

Hopefully this makes some sense.

Comment: So: What did you try? And what is wrong with your result?

Comment: I've tried a standard 301 redirect but it doesn't work with the query string. I struggle with htaccess, i don't find it very intuitive to learn.

Comment: Do you want to *redirect* or *rewrite* internally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^colours/yellow/?$ template?id=3 [L,NC,QSA]

RewriteRule ^colours/red/?$ template?id=5 [L,NC,QSA]
```